# Windows terminal on windows 11 gives error not finding nerd font

Tags: terminal, windows-11, fonts

Error when launching windows terminal

> WARNING
>
> Unable to find the selected font "Hack Nerd Font".
>
> "Consolas" has been selected instead.
>
> Please either install the missing font or choose another one

I am using windows terminal on windows 11

I installed nerd hack font https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v3.0.2/Hack.zip

I can see it in windows fonts listed

I have added it to the default profile on settings json

```
    "profiles": 
{
    "defaults": 
    {
        "font": 
        {
            "face": "Hack Nerd Font"
        },
        "opacity": 85,
        "useAcrylic": true
    },
```

but I still get the error

for now I have I reselect font and fixed the issue for that session but it does not stick.

Comment: Why does this happen every couple weeks? Very frustrating.

Comment: if you rebooted and it happens delete the font from fonts dir and reinstall the font from settings ui on windows

Comment: I've done that many times. The most recent fix I've tried is "Install for all users". So far so good. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After search I was able to find different way to install font. I initially installed the font by copying the fonts over to fonts directory (`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Fonts`). It shows installed in the system.

But if you search on windows 11 `Settings` app go to `personalisation` and then select `fonts` you find that windows 11 is not able to find the font there. So you just need to drag and drop the fonts here and it fixed my problem.

I think this is windows 11 possibly windows 10 issue due to how MS is making everything work from settings instead of control panel.

Comment: This step alone does the job. once the font face is set in the settings UI, manual update to the JSON file is not required.